# Unable to install sonarqube plugins for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, sonarqube

I'm trying to install the sonarqube plugins in Eclipse Luna on Windows. This is what I do:

- select `Help/Install new software...`
- select the `http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse/`
- select the `SonarQube Java`, `SonarQube ortional connectors` and `SonarQube Python` items and press `Next`
- After some churning I get to an `Install Remediation Page`, indicating thePython Analyzer will not be installed. If I select `Show original error and build my own solution` I see the following details:

  ```
  Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: SonarQube Python Analyser 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.pydev.feature.feature.group 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: SonarQube Integration for PyDev 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.pydev 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE) requires 'bundle org.python.pydev 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: SonarQube Python Analyser 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.pydev.feature.feature.group 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE)
  To: org.sonar.ide.eclipse.pydev [3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE]
  ```
- I Go back to  `keep my installation the same and modify the items being installed to be compatible`, trying to at least get the Java part installed, and press `Next`, then `Finish`
- I get a `Problem occurred` dialog, with the following details:

  ```
      An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
      session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
      No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt.feature,3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE
      No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.sonar.ide.eclipse.m2e,3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE
      No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.sonar.ide.eclipse.m2e.feature,3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE
  ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The following part of the error message tends to tell that you haven't installed Python support in Eclipse:

```
requires 'bundle org.python.pydev 0.0.0'
```

, which is required if you want to install support for Python SonarQube analyses.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the java part failing, any insight there?

Comment: Not really, this should be working fine (I actually installed the plugin not long ago on a laptop, so this is working correctly). Maybe you should start over from a clean install of Luna.